# Pandas auto converting text to #####

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to convert a space delimited text file into csv. When i convert it using pandas, I see the csv files has few issues. For one, my string columns 12/02/17 is convert to `######` while some get converted correctly

Also i see some values like 12/01/17 gets converted to 12/1/17 (it removes the leading zeros).

How can i solve these. Are there any other solutions?

These are my lines of code:

```
read_file = pd.read_csv(r'C:\FAST\Python\3.7.0\DataC.txt', sep='\s+', header=None, dtype=str)
read_file.to_csv(r'C:\FAST\Python\3.7.0\src1.csv ', index=None)
```

Comment: ####### is excels way of saying you need to expand the width of the column. I don't think that issue is a pandas issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might not be the conversion from pandas, but how MS Excel, I'm assuming, is displaying the content of the cell. When you open your CSV file using Excel, try using this shortcut:

Go to the column where it is happening and press
<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>

And if you wish to apply it to all columns, press
<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> & then <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>

Using this shortcut command will help you see all the columns of the csv, in full-width mode and thus no "xxxxx" format.

Comment: The above problem is solved it just shows data in #### but when expanded it is showing the value correctly

Comment: . I am facing another issue where in  i have given the separater value as \s+ .However the data in my text file has different variations  for example